# Map Backbone "save" method to Mongoose "post"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post, backbone.js, mongoose

How do I synch up Backbone models with Mongoose API? I am developing a Node.js SPA with Backbone.js on the client side and, Express and Mongoose on the server side. I have set up an api with Mongoose and it works when I post to the db from the console. Also, I have a Backbone view that is saving models on the client side.

Where do I add the code to map the two together? In my Backbone view? or in the Model? How do I pull my server side variables into the client?

Here is code:

Backbone View:

```
var ProductDetailsView2 = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {

    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);

},

render: function() {        

    $(this.el).html(_.map([
        '<a href="#/shopping-cart">Back to Store</a>' +
        '<form>' +
        '<h3>' + this.model.get('title') + '</h3>'+
        '<img src="photos/kitty-store/' + this.model.attributes.imagepathsm + '" class="img-polaroid" style="width:150px; max-height:100px; overflow:hidden;"/>' +
        '<span class="label">' + 'Quantity: ' + '</span>' + 
        '<input class="quantity" name="quantity" value="' + this.model.get('quantity') + '">' +
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Quantity</button><br/>' +
        '<span class="price">' + '$' + this.model.get('price') + '.00' + '</span><br/>' +
        '</form>' +
        '<span class="description">' + this.model.get('description') + '</span><br/>' +
        '<a href="#/orders/' + this.model.attributes._id + '">Add to shopping-cart</a>', this.model.calculateAmount(),

    ], function(val, key) {
        return '<li class="shopping-item">' + val + '</li>';    

    }));

    this.delegateEvents({
        'click .btn-primary' : 'save'
    })

    return this;
},

save: function() {
    this.setModelData();

        this.model.save(this.model.attributes,
        {
            success: function (model) {
                app.productsOrderedCollection.add(model);
                //can we ajax post here to the server???

            }
    }
        )
},

setModelData: function() {
    this.model.set({
        quantity: this.$el.find('input[name="quantity"]').val()

    })

  }
 });
```

Backbone Model:

```
var SupplyCategory = Backbone.Model.extend({

urlRoot: '/api/products',
idAttribute: "_id",
defaults: {

            "product_id": 3,
            "category": "supplies",
            "title": "Big Max Fountain",
            "id": "big-max-fountain",
            "url" : "big-max-fountain",
            "name": "Big Max Fountain",
            "keyword" : "Hydration",
            "description" : "Large capacity drinking fountain",
            "price" : "400",
            "quantity" : "2",
            "imagepathsm" : "big-max-fountain.jpg" 


        },



    calculateAmount: function () {
        return '<p class="total">' + 'Total: $' + this.get('price') * this.get('quantity') + '.00';
    },
});
```

Post to MongoDB:

```
//create a single product
app.post('/api/products', function (req, res) {
   var product;
   console.log("POST: ");
   console.log(req.body);
   product = new ProductModel ({
   id: req.body.id,
   category: req.body.category,
   title: req.body.title,
   url: req.body.url,
   keyword: req.body.keyword,
   description: req.body.description,
   price: req.body.price,
   quantity: req.body.quantity,
   imagepathsm: req.body.imagepathsm,
   modified: req.body.modified,

});
 product.save(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
     return console.log('added');
   } else {
    return console.log(err);
  }
});
  return res.send(product);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. I had to scrape the model data I wanted to post to the server, save it into variables and post it inside my success callback of the save function inside the Backbone view. Here is the updated save function from ProductDetailsView2:

```
save: function() {

    this.setModelData();

        this.model.save(this.model.attributes,
        {
            success: function (model) {

                app.productsOrderedCollection.add(model);

                //Post to the ordered Supplies Collection
                jQuery.post("/api/orders", {
                    "title": title,  
                    "description": description, 
                    "quantity" : quantity,
                    "price" : price 

                }, function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
                    console.log("Post response:"); console.dir(data); console.log(textStatus); console.dir(jqXHR); 
                });

            }

    })
         var description = this.model.get('description');
        var title = this.model.get('title');
        var quantity = this.model.get('quantity');
        var price = this.model.get('price');
},
```